# TFS Rest Api authorization issue in Python 2

Tags: python, rest, tfs

I am trying to access `TFS` REST API in `Python` 2 but getting `401 Authorization Error`. I am able to access API url from `web-browser` using same credentials. Also same credentials is working with `.Net` code. Tried with urllib2 library as guided in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811319/1838307). Any suggestion to access TFS api in Python2?

**tfs.py**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

username = '<UserName>'
password = '<Password>'
tfsApi = 'https://{myserver}/tfs/collectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0'

tfsResponse = requests.get(tfsApi, auth=(username, password))
if(tfsResponse.ok):
    tfsResponse = tfsResponse.json()
    print(tfsResponse)
else:
    tfsResponse.raise_for_status()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\tfs.py", line 13, in <module>
    tfsResponse.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 862, in raise_fo
r_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://{myserver}/tfs/collectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

.Net Working code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", AppConfig.TFS_API_USER, AppConfig.TFS_API_PASS))));
```

Comment: Do you use on-premise TFS or VSTS? Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server`, Version: `14.95.25229.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TFS uses [NTLM authentication protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874(v=vs.110).aspx) , Hence I have to update my code with HTTP NTLM authentication using the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests_ntlm/) library.

**Working code:**

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

username = '<DOMAIN>\\<UserName>'
password = '<Password>'
tfsApi = 'https://{myserver}/tfs/collectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0'

tfsResponse = requests.get(tfsApi,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username,password))
if(tfsResponse.ok):
    tfsResponse = tfsResponse.json()
    print(tfsResponse)
else:
    tfsResponse.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Cece-MSFT

Comment: What does domain + username look like? Can you give me a fake example?

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems you want to [get a list of team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#withcapabilities) with REST API. The API should look like:

-

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0
```

2. Make sure you have enabled Basic Auth for your TFS:

   - check your IIS to see whether the Basic authentication service role
     is installed.
   - go to IIS Manager, select Team Foundation Server -- Authentication
     and disable everything other than Basic Authentication. Then do the
     same for the tfs node under Team Foundation Server.
   - restart your IIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed api-version to `1.0` in API url, but still same issue.

Comment: It seems you are using TFS 2015. Have you enabled Basic Auth for your TFS as I posted?

Comment: Also, the url normally begin with http for on-premise server if you don't set up SSL.

Comment: We have SSL enable on server. Also enable the Basic Auth. But somehow its not working with request module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got the solutions. I have posted as a answer. May be it will helps to others.